# react from with text-box component that renders only after entering first 4 letters of value for multi-select option

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
 case 'multiselect':
        let multipleSelect = props => {
          let { input, filter, level, viz_type, handleChange } = props;
          return (
            <MultiValuePicker
              {...input}
              filter={filter}
              level={level}
              viz_type={viz_type}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          );
        };
        return (
          <Field
            key={filterObj.dimension_id}
            name={filterObj.dimension_id}
            component={multipleSelect}
            filter={filterObj}
            level={1}
            viz_type={this.props.viz_type}
            handleChange={this.props.handleFilterUpdate.bind(
              this,
              this.props.updateFilters,
              this.props.reportObj
            )}
          />
        );
```

here is a code for multi-select option in a react form, I want to select the values only after inserting first 4 letters of corresponding values.for example, if I have to select Karnataka I have to type in 'kara' and then it should render Karnataka.which component should I use...thanx in advance

Comment: you need to share MultiValuePicker and Field component.

Comment: sorry cant do that

Comment: ok so u should get some onInputChange which is not for selection of an option but on entering of value on input box.